# Numpy use specific rows and columns to form a new matrix

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
i = np.array([True, False, True])
j = np.array([True, True, False])
print(a[i, j])
print(a[i, :][:, j])
```

The first print:

```
[1 8]
```

The second print:

```
[[1 2]
 [7 8]]
```

What I want is the second one. Is there a better way than `a[i, :][:, j]`?

I feel this is not the correct way.

Comment: Why don't you like it?  It's explicit, it's short, and it's clear.

Comment: @TimRoberts a[i, :] will create a new array and a[i, :][:, j] will create the final result. There are 2 steps and 2 memory allocations. I think it should only take 1 step.

Answer (score 4):

The indices need to be reshaped. See the second example at [Purely integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing)

```
# Either q[i[:, np.newaxis], j] or a[np.ix_(i, j)]
# or a[i[:, None], j]
print(a[np.ix_(i, j)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the extra columns for `i`, just use:

```
print(a[i][:, j])
```

Output:

```
[[1 2]
 [7 8]]
```